# I have a todo app made by angular and the system sends some error

Tags: angular, typescript, http-status-code-405, http-status-code-500

When I want to post, the system sends the 405 error message back to the console.  I don't know how I made that, and how can I fix that.

Or if I press the done button then the console will return a 500 error message.

This is the HTML

```
<input
  (keyup.enter)="createPost(name)" #name
  type="text" class="form-control">
<ul class="list-group">
  <li
  *ngFor="let post of posts"
  [ngClass]="post.completed?'list-group-item list-group-item-success':'list-group-item'">
  <button
    (click)="updatePost(post)"
    class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" id="button">
    {{ post.completed ? 'Done' : 'Not ready' }}
  </button>
  <button
    (click)="deletePost(post)"
    class="btn btn-outline-danger ml-2 btn-sm">
    Delete
  </button>
  {{ post.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the TypeScript:

```
export class ToDoAppComponent {
  posts: any;
  private url = 'http://todoapp.test/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http.get(this.url).subscribe(response => {
      this.posts = response;
    });
  }



  createPost(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
    let post: any = { name: input.value }
    input.value = '';

    this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(post)).subscribe(response => {
      post.id = response.id;
      this.posts.splice(0, 0, post);

    });
  }

  updatePost(post) {
    this.http.put(this.url + '/' + post.id, JSON.stringify({ status: !post.status })).subscribe(response => {
      post.status = !post.status;

    });
  }

  deletePost(post) {
    this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + post.id, ).subscribe(response => {
      let index = this.posts.indexOf(post);
      this.posts.splice(index, 1);
    })
  }
}
```

Attached is the error message and the data received by the server[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Update CORS policy in the backend.

Comment: Did you try the to call the API endpoint over postman or something similar? Beside that it seems that you have a cors problem. You are calling `http://todoapp.test/api` form `http://localhost:4200`. You could solve that problem by creating a proxy for your local dev server [see here](https://itnext.io/angular-cli-proxy-configuration-4311acec9d6f) or update CORS policy in backend.

Comment: Yes I tried to test with Postman there the server works perfectly. @riorudo

Comment: Though you can get response in Postman and Chrome tab (using http://todoapp.test/api). It'll be blocked when called by application.

Comment: try setting content-type as application/json.. `this.http.post<T>(
      url,
      JSON.stringify(data),
      {headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });`

Answer (score -1):

Update CORS policy in backend to resolve 405 issue